# Visual Studio 2015 Crash all the time with Apache Cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I installed the official release version of Visual Studio 2015 with Apache Cordova, and created a simple project, using Android Simulator on my PC.

1. Visual Studio crashes or hangs all the time when I am debugging, I mean very often. These are some of the actions which can make it crash or hang

   > Refresh the simulator
   >        Close the simulator
   >        Active files in solution explorer
   >        Add a variable to watch window
   >     ......................
   >
   > ......................
2. When I start to debug it in the simulator, about 9 of 10 times it will fail with errors below, once it succeeds.

> ```
> [32mINFO:[39m Server instance running on: [36mhttp://localhost:4400[39m
> [32mINFO:[39m CORS XHR proxy service on: [36mhttp://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy[39m
> [32mINFO:[39m JSONP XHR proxy service on: [36mhttp://localhost:4400/ripple/jsonp_xhr_proxy[39m
> Cordova 3.0 Project detected...
> [32mINFO: [39mCould not find cordova as a local module. Expecting to find it installed globally.
> ```

Anybody has ideas about these problems? I feel this version's Visual Studio Apache Cordova is so so so buggy!

I tried on different computers, totally the same.

Update 1:

I found that after you tried to debug a couple of times, the Visual Studio's memory usage will go up to 4 GB. It seems that to restart visual studio can fix problem 2. This means I have to restart Visual Studio constantly.

Update 2:

I was so glad knowing Microsoft has a new update for Apache Cordova, Installed it, and so disppointed! Has ever anybody of Microsoft really tried to write a small piece of code to test this?  What bugs did they really fix?

Nothing changed, even worth,some worked functions are broken now!

Comment: how much ram do you have on your system?

Comment: one is 8GB, the outher one has 16GB

Comment: Would you be willing to help out identifying the bug? Do you have (or could you provide) a minimal project that reproduces the crash along with the steps leading up to the crash?

[Disclosure: I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft]

Comment: Same problem, bug fixed?

Comment: I haven't tried for a couple of month. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

try this,it is a known bug
try this,it is a known bug
try this,it is a known bug
try this,it is a known bug
try this,it is a known bug
try this,it is a known bug
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/147cd1a2-1f1a-4847-a256-0613cfea732d/rtm-known-issue-visual-studio-hangs-when-creating-a-new-cordova-project-or-intellisense-doesnt?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make difderence.